# jQuery - .each() over dynamically removed rows - numbering is off

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, each

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dxhen3ve/4/

Hey guys,

I've been trying to figure out the issue here for some time.

Essentially, I have a table with rows.  You can add new rows (works fine).  However, on the deletion of rows, I would like to re-number all of the rows below it (including all of their input names/ids within).

This works fine as I have it on the first time you click "remove" for any row.. say, if you have rows 0-4 and delete row 1, you will now have rows 0-3 and they will be numbered correctly--however, after that if you click remove again on another row, the numbers do not update

The indexes are getting mixed up some how and it almost seems like it's not recognizing that I've removed an element from the DOM.. when I console.log the indexes everything looks fine.

As an example:
- Add 5 rows (0-4)
- Remove row #1 (the rows below get updated as they should).
- Remove the new row #1, and you will see that row #2 takes its place instead of changing to row #1.
- In the function 'renumber_budget_rows', the if statement seems to get skipped for that row #2, even though I feel like it should meet the conditions (and is present if I console.log(item)

What am I missing?  https://jsfiddle.net/dxhen3ve/4/

** Update: Just wanted to update that I have a true resolution that works, which is great!  However, I am more interested in knowing WHY my solution is failing.  At the moment, the best I have, from the correct answer, was that my indexes were misaligned.  I'm going to take a new look at them.

HTML

```
                <script type="text/template" id="budget_row-template">                  

                <tr id="budget_row-{{index}}" class="budget-row" data-budget-index="{{index}}">

                    <td class="budget-line">{{index}}</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="budget_description-{{index}}" id="budget_description-{{index}}" class="budget-description" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="budget_amount-{{index}}" id="budget_amount-{{index}}" class="budget-amount" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="budget_costcode-{{index}}" id="budget_costcode-{{index}}" class="budget-costcode">
                            <option>-- Select Cost Code</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>

                    <td><a href="#" id="buget_row-{{index}}-addparent" class="table-btn neutral add-budget-child" title="Add Line: {{index}} Child" data-budget-index="{{index}}"><i class="fa fa-share"></i></a></td>
                    <td><a href="#" id="budget_row-{{index}}-trash" data-budget-index="{{index}}" class="table-btn danger trash-budget-row" title="Delete Line: {{index}}">remove</a></td>

                </tr>

            </script>
            <div class="table-scroll-container">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover tablesorter" id="budget-display">

                    <thead>
                        <tr>                    
                            <th>Line #</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                            <th>Cost Code</th>
                            <th data-sorter="false"></th>
                            <th data-sorter="false"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody id="test">

                        <tr id="budget_row-0" class="budget-row" data-budget-index="0">

                            <td class="budget-line">0</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="budget_description-0" id="budget_description-0" class="budget-description" /></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="budget_amount-0" id="budget_amount-0" class="budget-amount" /></td>
                            <td>
                                <select name="budget_costcode-0" id="budget_costcode-0" class="budget-costcode">
                                    <option>-- Select Cost Code</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td><a href="#" id="buget_row-0-addparent" class="table-btn neutral add-budget-child" title="Add Line: 0 Child" data-budget-index="0"><i class="fa fa-share"></i></a></td>
                            <td></td>

                        </tr>

                    </tbody>

                </table>
            </div>


            <div class="text-align-center">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success add-budget-row"><i class="icon icon-plus icon-white"></i> Add Line Item</a><br />
            </div>
```

JS

```
function renumber_budget_rows(removed) {
    $('#budget-display tbody .budget-row').each(function(indite, item) {
        var ti = $(item).data('budget-index');
  if( ti > removed ) {
            ti--;
            //console.log(item);
            $(item).attr('id', 'budget_row-'+ti);
            $(item).attr('data-budget-index', ti);
            $(item).find('.budget-line').html(ti);
            $(item).find('.budget-description').attr({ 'name': 'budget-description-'+ti, 'id': 'budget-description-'+ti });
            $(item).find('.budget-amount').attr({ 'name': 'budget-amount-'+ti, 'id': 'budget-amount-'+ti });
            $(item).find('.budget-costcode').attr({ 'name': 'budget-costcode-'+ti, 'id': 'budget-costcode-'+ti });
            $(item).find('.add-budget-child').attr({ 'id': 'budget_row-addparent-'+ti, 'data-budget-index': ti });
            $(item).find('.trash-budget-row').attr({ 'id': 'budget_row-'+ti+'-trash' });
            $(item).find('.trash-budget-row').attr('data-budget-index', ti);
        }
    });
}


var budget_index = 0;
$('.add-budget-row').click(function(e) {
    budget_index++;
    e.preventDefault();
    var budget_html = $('#budget_row-template').html();
    budget_html = budget_html.replace(/{{index}}/g, budget_index);
    $('#budget-display tbody').append(budget_html);




});
$('#budget-display').on('click', '.trash-budget-row', function(e) {
    var removed = $(this).data('budget-index');
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    console.log(removed);


    renumber_budget_rows(removed);
    budget_index--;

});
```

Comment: You might consider not doing any of the renumbering until the very end when you have to submit. Makes it a lot simpler. There is no need to change ID's, don't even use ID's... just modify input element names or use array names which is even simpler and require no script at all

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for the comment! This is very true and I was able to realize (using arrays for the inputs) from the beginning; however, at the time I'm just putting together fake scenarios to help myself better learn jQuery as I feel my skills/understanding are lacking (as you could have probably noticed).

Comment: Just talking from experience. I used to do same sort of manipulation until I realized it was over complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are deleting the row, after a row deletion, you can iterate through every tr using `.each()` function and change the attributes based on the index `i` value.

```
$('#budget-display').on('click', '.trash-budget-row', function(e) {
        var removed = $(this).data('budget-index');
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        $('tbody tr').each(function(i){
          $(this).find('td').eq(0).text(i);
          $(this).attr("data-budget-index",i);
          $(this).attr("id","budget-row-" + i);
        });    
    budget_index--;    
});
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/dxhen3ve/5/

Comment: This works, thanks to you!

I'm assuming the issue in my version was that my manually set indexes were misaligned?  I am going to try to see if I can fix it, but I definitely see why your result works.

Thanks again